Which versions are compatible with each other for the packaged react-native-vision-camera, react-native-worklets-core, vision-camera-face-detector?
Iam using expo bare workflow. Iam trying to do live face detection using react-native-vison-camera, this react-native-vison-camera package installed correctly and iam able to open camera , For detecting faces i need to use vision-camera-face-detector and react-native-worklets-core. If i install this and try to build the app iam getting cmake errors, i think the versions of react-native-vison-camera and vision-camera-face-detector and react-native-worklets-core are mismatching, can anyone help me regarding correct version numbers or help me to solve the error.
Thanks in Advance.
This is my package.json file
{
  "name": "facerec",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-ml-kit/face-detection": "^1.3.2",
    "expo": "~52.0.8",
    "expo-status-bar": "~2.0.0",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.76.2",
    "vision-camera-face-detector": "^0.1.8",
    "react-native-vision-camera": "4.5.2",
    "react-native-worklets-core": "1.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}

